# Change value of specific textbox by using pulldown menus and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

hope someone can help me out here.
i would like 2 pulldown menus to change the value of a textbox, but with certain conditions.
ill explain after the code, as a start this is what i have now, but im struggling :

```
    <select class="select" name="pafgifte" id="pafgifte" onchange="updateInput()">
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 500; $i++) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>

<select class="select" name="pstatus1" onchange="updateInput()">
<option selected value="2">Order</option>
<option value="1">Onstock</option>
</select>

<input type="text" maxlength="6" name="pontvangen" size="1" value="0">

<script>
function updateInput(){
    var pafgifte = document.getElementsByName("pafgifte")[0].value;
    var pstatus1 = document.getElementsByName("pstatus1")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("pontvangen")[0].value = pafgifte;

}

</script>
```

If you change the value of the selectbox pafgifte i would like that value to be copied to textbox pontvangen value (ok this is easy)

but then when i change the selectbox pstatus1 and the selected value=1 (Onstock) i want the textbox value pontvangen to be 0, but then when i reselect value=2 (Order) i want the textbox pontvangen value to be the selected value of pafgifte.

I would like the values of pstatus1 (1 and 2) intact because these are saved into a table in the database.

Is there an easier way to do this?
Could someone help me out here?, help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with this function:

```
function updateInput(){
    var pafgifte = document.getElementsByName("pafgifte")[0].value;
    var pstatus1 = document.getElementsByName("pstatus1")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("pontvangen")[0].value = pstatus1 == 1 ? '0' : pafgifte;
}
```

Comment: This works great, this is what i needed thank you sooo much!!! :-) –